# How to generate a random array for simple dungeon map?

Tags: php, arrays, json, dictionary, coordinates

I've been working on a very simple dungeon creator. The idea is that I provide an `x_axis` and `y_axis` length to determine the size of the map, then randomly generate an array containing 0s, for nothing, and 2 for a room.

Depending on the size of the map, this will determine the number of rooms `floor((x * y) / 2)`, but sometimes less rooms are created and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
<?php
// Check if this was a POST request
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Set variables
    $x_axis = $_POST['x_axis'];
    $y_axis = $_POST['y_axis'];

    // Build the arrays
    $x_array = array_fill(0, $x_axis, 0);
    $y_array = array_fill(0, $y_axis, 0);
    $coordinates = [];

    // Loop through the x array
    foreach($x_array as $x => $v)
    {
        // Add the y_array at position x in the coordinates
        $coordinates[$x] = $y_array;
    }

    // Set variables
    $x_max = $x_axis - 1;
    $y_max = $y_axis - 1;
    $rooms_max = floor(($x_axis * $y_axis) / 2);

    // Pick a random starting point along the x axis
    $start = mt_rand(0, $x_max);

    // Generate the map
    $map = _generate_room($coordinates, $start, 0, 1, $rooms_max, $x_max, $y_max);

    // Return the map
    echo json_encode($map);
}

function _generate_room($c, $x, $y, $r, $rm, $xm, $ym)
{
    // Set this value to a room (2)
    $c[$y][$x] = 2;

    // Have we reached the max number of rooms?
    if($r != $rm)
    {
        // Increase the room
        $r = $r + 1;

        // Generate the next coordinate
        $next_coord = _generate_coord($c, $x, $y, $xm, $ym);

        // Create a new room
        $c = _generate_room($c, $next_coord[0], $next_coord[1], $r, $rm, $xm, $ym);
    }

    // Return the coordinates
    return $c;
}

function _generate_coord($c, $x, $y, $xm, $ym)
{
    // Are we changing the x (0) or y(1)
    $change = mt_rand(0, 1);

    // Changing the x
    if($change === 0)
    {
        // Set the new_x variable
        if($x === 0)
        {
            $x = 1;
        } elseif($x === $xm)
        {
            $x = $xm - 1;
        } else {
            // Choose 0 or 1
            $res = mt_rand(0, 1);

            // Decrease
            if($res === 0)
            {
                $x = $x - 1;
            // Increase
            } else
            {
                $x = $x + 1;
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        // Set the new_y variable
        if($y === 0)
        {
            $y = 1;
        } elseif($y === $ym)
        {
            $y = $ym - 1;
        } else {
            // Choose 0 or 1
            $res = mt_rand(0, 1);

            // Decrease
            if($res === 0)
            {
                $y = $y - 1;
            // Increase
            } else
            {
                $y = $y + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Fetch the room
    $room = $c[$x][$y];

    // Does the room already contain a 2?
    if($room === 2)
    {
        return _generate_coord($c, $x, $y, $xm, $ym);
    }

    return [$x, $y];
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using more helpful/descriptive variable and parameter names. When you toss around names like `$x`, `$r`, and `$ym`, anyone who reads your code (including future you!) has to constantly refer back up the function call stack just to figure out what's going on. Someone should be able to reasonably understand your code at a glance. It will save you (and anyone else who needs to understand your code) a lot of headaches in the future if you fix your code style now and use greater discipline with your code style moving forward. It's difficult to help otherwise :)

Comment: If you e.g. make a room at 1, 1 and decide to make a room at 0, 1 then you will make that 0 into 1 and make a room at the same place? Not sure, this code is really hard to understand.